# Should maven modules have their own trunk folder?

Tags: java, maven, svn

I have the following project structure and wonder if each of them should have their own trunk folder?

```
myproject/trunk/myproject-commons
myproject/trunk/myproject-web
myproject/trunk/myproject-soap
```

`commons` is of course shared among the others. The `web` app should be released on a weekly basis, the `soap` project monthly only.

Should I stick to this structure that all projects are within the same trunk folder? Or should each project have its own trunk?

```
myproject/myproject-commons/trunk/
myproject/myproject-web/trunk/
myproject/myproject-soap/trunk/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the modules may depend on one another, I would persist them in one the same place. Otherwise, you won't be able to build module `A` after you checkout it, if it depends on module `B` (which is under another trunk).

I think this structure is convenient:

```
trunk/myproject/myproject-soap/
trunk/myproject/myproject-web/
trunk/myproject/myproject-commons/
```